# How do I set 64-bit alignment for gcc from the command line?

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, alignment

In the man page I only found 8, 16 and 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-falign-*` options: `-falign-functions`, `-falign-labels`, `-falign-jumps`.

Or, on i386/x86_64, if it's the stack boundary you want to keep aligned, use `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=6` (2^6 = 64).

Comment: I need allign field in all structs. other is not interested